# Creating .apk from another .apk

Tags: android

Can someone tell me if it's possible to create an apk file during runtime?

I'll explain:

I want to create a Android app  that can create apk (android apps) when I run it

it will be like:

```
start the app
set application parameters (number of buttons in the menu, links, images, etc..)
press create
install the apk file on the phone or save that .apk in the server
```

hope you understand ^^" and thx for any help (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should very well be possible. AIDE has been doing it for a while - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

Comment: How to do this app.. can u plz give some guide lines

Comment: @joy_pr there won't be any guidelines anywhere. That's a full compiler running on top of the Android framework. It is not an easy task. I believe most (if not all) of the Android SDK and ADT is open source, so you're free to grab the code tweak it to your own needs and put in an app. But do not expect to accomplish that with 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to create a app that takes parameter for all the UI you expect to show and once UI is finalized and user click save. The inner module use the information and create the App, its more like not showing customization part of your app to user again and again, rather route the user to the finalized views.

Once finalized the meta data can be stored to server. Its more like developing skins.

Comment: not converting to apk, there will be only one apk, rest will be the guidelines as what needs to be make. i.e user says he need 3 itmes in menu, you have a page with a spinner of number of menu items, so as soon as user say he want 3 you show 3 edittext with names for menu. User then can link menu to action that the menu should take.

Comment: After creating that, i want to create a new .apk(new APP). i want to know how to create an .apk using another android appl...